# Export a Grid With Kendo PDF

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2, kendo-ui-grid

I'm trying to export an entire page with the Kendo Angular PDF, this works fine except when I add a Kendo Angular Grid on to the page.  I'm seeing issues where rows are missing and there is extra blank space on some of the pages.

Here is a sample with the behavior.  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qkj4p7
Notice that it skips from id 11 to 19 between the first and second page and that there is a large margin at the bottom of the pages.

It seems like part of the issue is that it picks where to do page breaks based upon the current DOM, instead of the copied DOM after the k-pdf-export style has been applied.  Has anyone figured out a way around this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The styles need to be applied kendo-pdf-document to do the styling instead of .k-pdf-export, [see example here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qkj4p7-gbjgrk?file=app/pdf-styles.css).  Telerik has updated their [documentation](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/pdfexport/content-styling/) to include this.